# Is it possible to make a definite prediction by training on discrete targets?

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network, regression, training-data

the question does seem a bit complicated by I will explain clearly what I want to achieve. So my company has provided me this data that I can use it for training the model.

| PartsProdM1 | PartsProdM2 | PartsProdM3 | ...OtherFeatures... | M1-D | M1-D | M1-D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 344 | 870 | .................... | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 450 | 900 | 540 | .................... | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 300 | 600 | 200 | .................... | 1 | 0 | 1 |

So from the above table column names has the following meaning:

1. PartsProdM1 / M2 / M3 - are the parts produced by machine 1, 2 and 3
2. other features can be - machine name, product name, etc
3. M1-D / M2-D / M3-D - are the targets and they mean if M1 / M2 and M3 is damaged i.e. if 0 -
   Not Damaged (0 %) || if 1 - Damaged (100%)

The Task:

Is to to create a regression model from this training data that can give prediction sort of like this:

| M1-D | M1-D | M1-D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40.89 | 35 | 37.89 |
| 55 | 44.6 | 76 |
| 71.5 | 98.9 | 87 |

I know it sounds ridiculous to make accurate predictions just by training on targets 0 and 1's
but is there any way or past references where I can make this thing work?

My company says that they have no way to provide the desired target info for training i.e. they can only say if a machine is broken (1) or not (0).

Currently, I am using a neural net to make this prediction with MSE loss function.

Comment: I am looking at a classification task. For each label (M1-D, M2-D, and M3-D), you need to output a number between 0 and 1 and that's exactly what most binary classifiers will output. Usually, we would set a threshold so that every value above it is rounded as 1, and below it would be 0. In your case, I would just take the given probability multiplied by 100 as the output.

Comment: @JosmyFaure Yes that's exactly what I doing right now, but is there a way to justify the accuracy of those probabilities?

Comment: I guess the accuracy of the probabilities can only as good as the accuracy of the model. Therefore, I would start by testing the model's accuracy on held-out validation data. If the accuracy is high then I would explain the logic behind the model and why I chose that specific model.